# JavaFX NodeOrientation StackOverflowError

Tags: java, javafx, stack-overflow, fxml, runtimeexception

I develop a JavaFX application and I've come across a very strange error. I guess it has something to do with my .FXML file, but I have no idea what exactly. The stack trace says it concerns the methods of the Scene class, which are connected with node orientation. Suprising is the fact, that I do not manipulate this property in the .FXML file or anywhere else at all, therefore I have no idea why this error happens everytime I click the button that is responsible for opening the new window created with this .FXML (generated by SceneBuilder).

I would appreciate all the help and ideas you could have in this matter. Thank you very much.

The StackOverflowException:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getWindow(Scene.java:623)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6228)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6188)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.calcEffectiveNodeOrientation(Scene.java:6240)
    ...
```

My .FXML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="pl.nombritech.Produktor.view.UstawieniaController">
    <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Ustawienia">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </Label>
        <Accordion fx:id="accordion" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <panes>
                <TitledPane fx:id="kategoriaTP" text="Kategoria">
                    <content>
                        <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true"
                            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                            <content>
                                <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                                    <children>
                                        <ListView fx:id="kategoria_ListaLV" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                                            <children>
                                                <TextField fx:id="kategoria_NazwaTF" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                                <Button fx:id="kategoria_DodajB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#handleKategoria_DodajB" text="Dodaj" />
                                                <Button fx:id="kategoria_UsunB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#handleKategoria_UsunB" text="Usuń" />
                                            </children>
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane text="Producent">
                    <content>
                        <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true"
                            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                            <content>
                                <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                                    <children>
                                        <ListView fx:id="producent_ListaLV" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                                            <children>
                                                <TextField fx:id="producent_NazwaTF" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                                <Button fx:id="producent_DodajB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#handleProducent_DodajB" text="Dodaj" />
                                                <Button fx:id="producent_UsunB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#handleProducent_UsunB" text="Usuń" />
                                            </children>
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane text="Sklep">
                    <content>
                        <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true"
                            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                            <content>
                                <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                                    <children>
                                        <ListView fx:id="sklep_ListaLV" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                                            <children>
                                                <TextField fx:id="sklep_NazwaTF" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                                <Button fx:id="sklep_DodajB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#handleSklep_DodajB" text="Dodaj" />
                                                <Button fx:id="sklep_UsunB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#handleSklep_UsunB" text="Usuń" />
                                            </children>
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
            </panes>
        </Accordion>
        <ButtonBar maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
            <buttons>
                <Button fx:id="zamknijB" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAnulujB"
                    text="Zamknij" />
            </buttons>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </ButtonBar>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

EDIT: Code used to open the new stage after clicking the button:

```
    @FXML
private void handleUstawieniaB(ActionEvent e)
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Ustawienia.fxml"));

    Parent root = null;
    try
    {
        root = loader.load();
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("Produktor");
    stage.initOwner(stage);
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    Scene scena = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scena);

    UstawieniaController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setStage(stage);

    // a method used to set some initial data in the new window, it doesn't change anything if I turn it off, so i don't think it is meaningful here
    controller.rozpocznij();

    stage.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code used to load the FXML and create the scene & stage?

Comment: @sillyfly of course, I've just included it at the bottom of the main post :)

Comment: Ah, I believe your problem is the line `stage.initOwner(stage);`, which creates a circular reference. The owner of a stage should be the stage that caused it to open, or null if it's a top-level window.

Comment: aaa yes, you may be right :) I had a getter there called getStage(), but when I realized, that it doesn't have any external use, I changed it to the class field called "stage" and I must have forgotten, that I used such a local variable as a reference to this newly created stage before :) I must have overlooked it somehow... I'll try it in a minute, but I think you're right, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @sillyfly yes, you were right :) thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1):

In the line of the Java code, where you are setting:

```
stage.initOwner(stage);
```

It causes the error. You need to set another stage to be the owner of the new stage. You cannot say that the `stage1` is the owner of the `stage1`.

Try to create another stage or use other.